# Event not working properly on IE 8 and IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

The following code is working fine in other browsers, but is not on IE8 and IE9 :

```
$('.filters-widget.bordered input[type="checkbox"]').bind("click", function () {
formSubmit();
});

function formSubmit() {
    this.document.getElementById("filters-form").submit();
}
```

My Html

```
<div class="filters-widget bordered">
<span class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0px 0px; "></span><input type="checkbox" id="sidecity-control-name-2" name="sidecity" class="styled" value="Brisbane">
<label for="sidecity-control-name-2">Brisbane (109)</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any Javascript errors? If so, what are they? What other browsers have you tested in that it does work with? What version of jQuery are you using? What does the `formSubmit()` function do? What does the HTML this code runs against look like?

Comment: what is inside the formSubmit function?

Comment: where is a) the rest of the code ? b) the HTML ? and c) the error message ?

Comment: Your selector looks funny.  Should there be a space between ".filters-widget" and ".bordered"?  EDIT - Never mind, that's probably valid.

Comment: @DanA. What looks funny about it? That checks for an element with both classes.

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7 or later, use .on() instead of .bind() to attach event handlers.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Yeah, I realized that after posting my comment.

Comment: I use 1.6.1 Maybe this behavior throught this attribute in HTML- jQuery16103206130437146121="249" `<SPAN style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 0px 0px" class=checkbox></SPAN><INPUT id=sidecity-control-name-0 class=styled name=sidecity value=Adelaide type=checkbox jQuery16103206130437146121="249"> <LABEL for=sidecity-control-name-0 jQuery16103206130437146121="296">Adelaide (63)</LABEL> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you try following:

```
$('.filters-widget.bordered input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    formSubmit();
});
```

Or maybe you need to insert a space character between ".filters-widget" and ".bordered"?

Comment: How it is different from .bind ("click".. ? .click is the short form of .bind("click" or .on("click".. internally all those goes in the same path.  ".click method is a shortcut for .bind("click", handler), as well as for .on("click", handler) as of jQuery 1.7"  ~ jQuery docs